# Generating List of N Random Numbers Between a Range of Numbers

Tags: python, syntax

I'd like to generate a list of n_length consisting of randomly generated numbers within a defined range.  What I'd like to know is whether I'm missing something built-in, something that would allow me to do this in the future in a more pythonic and cleaner way.  Thanks for any thoughts.

```
In [59]: from random import randrange

In [60]: x_list    = [0]*100

In [61]: rand_list = [randrange(700, 1500) for x in x_list]
```

Basically, I don't like my `x_list` because I think it's kind of arbitrary, and I doubt that I'm the first person ever to encounter this problem, especially where databases store so much info as indices.  Is there a better way of solving this?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
rand_list = [randrange(700, 1500) for _ in xrange(100)]
```

Comment: @BeeSmears : It is a convention in Python to use `_` as a variable name for a variable not being used. Since, `x` plays no role in the list comprehension, it is replaced by `_`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better if you don't care about the distribution:

```
>>> random.sample(xrange(700, 1500), 100)
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing, as it'll never have the same number show up twice.

Comment: If the distribution is not cared, this will be a good solution? I just wonder.@DSM

Comment: @zhangyangyu Thank you.  I think it is comparable to w.m's answer in this case b/c distribution shouldn't matter.  The list comprehension is more flexible, I think, so perhaps it might be preferred if I needed a conditional -- e.g. `[randrange(700, 1500) for x in xrange(100) if x not in list]`

Comment: Yes. I said if you don't care about the distribution. Also you can add a condition with list comprehension. But this method is quicker. So, if you don't care about the distribution and condition and speed matters, you can use this one.@BeeSmears