# How to create a list of length L with random numbers ranging from 1 to N in Python?

Tags: python, list, random

In other words if I call getList(10,6) then it'd be a list of length 10 with numbers ranging from 1 to 6, repeats allowed. For example [1,4,2,6,3,8,5,5,2,1]

Do I just call randrage and append repeatedly? Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use the search and find a similar question that was asked 5 hours ago: [Generating List of N Random Numbers Between a Range of Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749629/generating-list-of-n-random-numbers-between-a-range-of-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import random

def getList(L, N):
    return [random.randint(1,N) for _ in xrange(L)]
```